# Understanding GC: Allocation failure and filled OldGen with temporary String objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

I have followed up with a couple of good questions and their answers but I still have a doubt.

This is what I understand and would like to see if the understanding is correct.

**GC (Allocation Failure)** kicks in whenever new memory is to be allocated on YoungGen.

Also, the fact that depending on the size of the object, some objects might have to be pushed to OldGen and significantly larger objects could directly be moved to OldGen.

**Application Behavior:** The reason for 'Allocation Failure' was the creation of huge strings. On debugging further with JFR and HeapDump, everything points to a lot of char[] and String objects which are created in our system on a temporary basis (i.e. YoungGen candidate). Some of these strings indeed are huge (~25KB each). Although, there was enough space available in the YoungGen as per the error message and Heap is not even close to maximum memory possible.

During the same time, OldGen was increasing and was not getting cleaned even after full GC. There could be another memory leak but there is nothing that points to that. So, I don't understand why OldGen remains at the same level even after the full GC.

**Apart from the validation of my understanding, the question is**: *Can the creation of a lot of temporary String/char[] objects (via strA + strB, new String()/StringBuilder().toString(), String.split(), String.substring(), Stream->buffer conversion etc.) cause GC to run very frequently even when the application has a lot of memory available in the YoungGen and heap in general? If yes, when and what are the alternatives?*

Thanks!

Comment: There are some additional info that would possibly help to answer. What JVM are you running? Version? Do you specifiy GC or GC flags?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer is a conditional yes.

Remember that young gen is split into 3 parts, eden, S0 and S1 which means that you do not have as much memory in young gen as you might think. If you overflow one of the survivor spaces, the remainder will be pushed to old gen (premature promotion), filling up old gen. Note also that promotion from young gen to old is based on the number of gc cycles. If you have frequent young gen gc where objects supposed to be short-lived are moved to old gen (because you have not finished with the temp objects), then you will fill up old gen. Note also that that just because you do a full gc, there are no guarantees that you will actually get any memory back.
So, use a tool like censum to analyse your gc logs and look especially for premature promotion. 
It might be that you will have to resize your young gen/old gen ratio.